# Polymorphism mimic for class in packages

Tags: java, polymorphism, package, mime

OOP allows for inheritance for abstract methods, thus every child with own implementation. Such ability cascades to coding an application in general, as such, it calls to one same message at different times and receive different output according to the type of child instantiated. This concept is known as Polymorphism.

Picture it that Polymorphism gives a developer a chance to create an object. This object can be assigned a reference to one of multiple classes' instances that both contain a method of the same signature but of different implementation. This assignment is through conditional statements. Thereafter calling the method using this object, which in turn, happens to perform different operations depending on the appropriate condition.

With the same view but now we are dealing with a Java Application that has many packages that both contain a Class of the same name. A scenario all users of the Application go through a Login class then routes to a Main Menu screen (Main class). There are two different users thus two versions of the Main class, each of which are in two packages (be it: admin and user), in turn, acting as an entry point for the rest of the appropriate package.

Is there a Polymorphism mimic to let us declare an object in the Login class, of which during authentication, then assign a reference to either package mapping from the user type?

Thereafter, calling `reference.Main.setVisible(true);` will open the Main class for the type of the current login user.

Comment: No need to use half the question to give us the definition of polymorphism.

Comment: ... unless that's the way the question was given to him

Comment: Thanks A--C, it's my first time here. McAlex, this is no question to me but from me.

Comment: My intention is to soft-code my programming. I have packages that contain all `JFrame`s for each of the users. Each of the packages contain the entry class `Main`. After authentication, I just want to have one statement like `Main.setVisible(true);` perhaps edited to `package.Main.setVisible(true);` where package is the reference to one of the packages (of the current user).

Comment: The more concise you can keep your question, the more likely people will be able/happy to help you out quickly.

Comment: I guess as they 'better luck next time'. As for @alexwhan: will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have both versions of the menu implement an interface/abstract class. Then use the interface polymorphically in the login class.

For example, make an abstract class called Menu, and have the userMenu and the adminMenu classes extend Menu. In your Login class, create a field of type Menu (for the sake of example call it m). Assign either a new UserMenu or AdminMenu at runtime, depending on who the user is. Then when you want to open the menu, call `m.setVisible(true)`

Comment: I wish there was way to Private Message you. @jedyobidan : Just for the sake of learning, ain't there a way to assign the reference to a package into a variable or object.

Comment: Such that I can code once the authentication process. For the case of adding another user type, I just add a package and a record to the database without editing the Login class.

Comment: Sounds like you need a factory method. Create a method called `public static Menu getMenu(String type)` that returns the appropriate class of object based on an input string. You'll still have to edit that method every time you add a new user type.

But if you really want to assign the menu variable just using the name of the class, you're probably going to need reflection.

Comment: You know reflection is a very advanced topic, so I will have one hell of a week for it. But once again thank you very much @jedyobidan.